# Inspecting non-variable state from a breakpoint in Workbench

Tags: workbench, debugging

Suppose I'm stopped at a breakpoint in Workbench, say at one of the `y = ...` lines in:

```
foo[a_] := Block[{y}, 
    If[Sin[a] > 0,
        y = -1,
        y = 1
        ]
    ]
```

How can I find out what `Sin[a]` is?  Or more generally do some other evaluation using the current state of my program?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can enter arbitrary expressions in the *Expressions* debugging view:

[image: screenshot of Wolfram Workbench debugger]

The function `VariableValue` must be used in such expressions in order to access any active variables.

If the *Expressions* view is not visible, you can open it from the Workbench main menu using *Window* / *Show View...* / *Expressions*.