# workbench: how to see values of global variables during debugging

Tags: workbench

Consdier the following package

```
BeginPackage["packageName`"];
   exportedFunction::usage = "...";
   Begin["`Private`"];
      globalVariable = Null;
      initializePackage[args___] := (globalVariable = workOn1[args]);
      exportedFunction[args___] := 
         Block[{localVariable},
            If[globalVariable===Null, Abort[]];
            localVariable = workOn2[globalVariable, args];
            workOn3[localVariable]
         ];
      workOn1[args___] := ...;
      workOn2[gv_, args___] := ...;
      workOn3[lv_] := ...;
   End[];
EndPackage[];
```

and assume that is being debugged in a workbench session, and that a break point has been set somewhere in exportedFunction. The debugger reports on the values of localVariable, but I can never see the value of  globalVariable. Is there a way to inspect the value of globalVariable as well?

Comment: closely related: [Inspecting non-variable state from a breakpoint in Workbench](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/463/142)

Comment: @WReach: I think, though I might be wrong, that this post is not closely related to the example you linked. In the exapmpel that you are pointing to the variable (a) is local. I am asking specifically about global variables. Did I missunderstood something?

Comment: OK, I've added an answer to explain more fully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Workbench's `Expressions` debugging view allows to evaluate any arbitrary expression, including global variables.  While stopped at a breakpoint, press the `Create a new watch expression` button in the `Expressions` view and enter the name of the global variable as the expression.  If the *Expressions* view is not visible, you can open it from the Workbench main menu using *Window* / *Show View...* / *Expressions*.

In contrast, if one wants to inspect a *local* variable `x` one must use the watch expression `VariableValue[x]`.

We are not limited to referencing global and local variables.  Any expression can be watched (see [Inspecting non-variable state from a breakpoint in Workbench](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/463/142) for a screenshot).

Comment: I understand finally! I tried it though, and could not make it work. The expression (a global private variable in the package) never evaluates. Do I have to reference with the full name (including the context)?

Comment: @zorank Yes, a private variable would need to be fully qualified.  For example, ``packageName`Private`globalVariable`` (from the question).

Comment: Domo arigato! It works! Just tested it.